# Material Design datatable .table-bordered and .table-striped at the same time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, material-design

I set up a dashboard with the Material Design and bootstrap. Now I tried to get borders around all cells and I tried to color each second row.

The problem is now that the two classes .table-striped and .table-bordered do not work together as I want.

My idea was a table where all cells have a border and every second row is colored. Actual in the colored line are no borders visible.

This does not work too:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:  #e6ffe6;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #FFF; }
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Here is my actual site:

[image]

EDIT:

My code:

```
 <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" data-background-color="green">
                                <h4 class="title">1. Personal</h4>
                                <p class="category">1.1 Arbeitszeit</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content table-responsive table-maxheight" style="overflow:scroll;">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-mc-green">
                                    <thead class="text-primary">
                                        <th class="thbackground">ID</th>
                                        <th class="thbackground">Gleitzeitrahmen</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Abweichungen</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Mehrarbeitervolumen</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Mehrarbeit</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Ausgleich</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Mehrarbeit</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Personalma&szlig;nahmen</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Sind &Uuml;berstunden abzusehen?</th>
                                        <th class="thbackground">Kl&auml;rungsbedarfe</th>
                                        <th class="thwidth thbackground">Kl&auml;rungsbedarfe Beschreibung</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <?php
                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result_table_main) > 0){
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_table_main)) {
                                            echo '<tr>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['id'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Gleitzeitrahmen'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Abweichungen'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeitervolumen'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeit1'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Ausgleich'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeit2'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Personalmassnahmen'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Ueberstunden_abzusehen'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Klaerungsbedarfe1'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $row['name_Klaerungsbedarfe2'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?> 
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: pease do not only show images but a minimal example of your code

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap right? [table-bordered and table-striped](https://jsfiddle.net/mq20ktqf) works without problem, [custom striping with borders](https://jsfiddle.net/mq20ktqf/1/) works too if you restrict it to `tbody`, so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Ok i edited my post with my code. In tbody is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possibility to manage this.

I comment out this code in the CSS:

```
.table>tbody>tr {
position: relative;
}
```

Now it works.